# How can I stop SQL Server query from returning multile rows for the same item ID in this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

First let me say this: I cannot use the `Distinct` keyword. There are column types in the returned data that it cannot compare.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    tblTemp.maxBid, tblAbsentee.abs_bid_price, 
    tblAbsentee.abs_date, tblSale.sale_name, tblSale.sale_date,
    tblItem.*,
    tblTemp.bid_count
FROM 
    tblAbsentee 
INNER JOIN 
    tblItem ON tblAbsentee.abs_item_id = tblItem.item_id AND tblAbsentee.abs_sale_id = tblItem.item_sale_id 
INNER JOIN 
    tblBidder ON tblAbsentee.abs_bidder_id = tblBidder.bidder_number AND tblAbsentee.abs_sale_id = tblBidder.bidder_sale_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    tblSale ON tblAbsentee.abs_sale_id = tblSale.sale_id 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(tblAbsentee.abs_id) As bid_count, 
        CASE 
            WHEN NOT (MAX(tblAbsentee.abs_bid_price) IS NULL) THEN MAX(tblAbsentee.abs_bid_price) ELSE 0 
        END As maxBid, 
        tblItem.item_id 
     FROM 
        tblAbsentee 
     INNER JOIN 
        tblItem ON tblAbsentee.abs_item_id = tblItem.item_id AND tblAbsentee.abs_sale_id = tblItem.item_sale_id 
     INNER JOIN  
        tblBidder ON tblAbsentee.abs_bidder_id = tblBidder.bidder_number AND tblAbsentee.abs_sale_id = tblBidder.bidder_sale_id 
     LEFT JOIN 
        tblSale ON tblAbsentee.abs_sale_id = tblSale.sale_id 
     WHERE 
        DATEADD(day, 7, tblSale.sale_date) >= GETDATE() 
     GROUP BY
        tblItem.item_id) As tblTemp On tblItem.item_id = tblTemp.item_id AND tblAbsentee.abs_bid_price = tblTemp.maxBid 
WHERE 
    DATEADD(day, 7, tblSale.sale_date) >= GETDATE() 
    AND tblBidder.bidder_mail_id = 13096 
ORDER BY 
    tblItem.item_lot ASC
```

So long as the bidder only leaves one bid, this works fine. But as soon as the bidder leaves another bid I get the error

> System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Due to using a data table for the results.

Here's some short sample data:

```
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|Max Bid |Abs_bid_price|abs_date            |item_id|
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|600.0000|600.0000     |1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM|135827 |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|600.0000|600.0000     |1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM|135827 |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|600.0000|600.0000     |1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM|135827 |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|600.0000|600.0000     |1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM|135827 |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|600.0000|600.0000     |1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM|135827 |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|600.0000|600.0000     |1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM|135827 |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
|20.0000 |20.0000      |1/15/2014 2:42:16 PM|123562 |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+-------+
```

I'm not going to bother putting in all of the columns. Just trust me when I say that they all contain the same data. In most cases, the `abs_date` column would NOT be the exact same. This was just a fluke. In either case, I would like to just group it by item_id and sort it by the abs_date field asc when grouping so that the first max bid left will be the one shown. If this was MySQL it'd be easy. I just don't know enough about SQL Server to figure this out, unfortunately, and cannot find a similar issue. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

It may not have been clear in my question, but I could validly get multiple rows returned, I just want to only get one of each item ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Common Table Expression. This will return the first occuring item_id.

```sql
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY abs_date) Rank
    FROM tblAbsentee
    ...
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Rank = 1
```

Comment: But will this work when there are 2 or more valid rows that should be returned?  For instance, 2 different item ID's?  It may not have been clear in my question, but I could validly get multiple rows returned, I just want to only get one of each item ID.

Comment: @James the above will return 1 record per item_id, this is dictated by the `PARTITION BY` section of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, it assigns a number to each row, starting at 1 for each item/group of items included in the `PARTITION BY`

Comment: @James - yes (it should). The `partition by` of the `ROW_NUMBER` function will reset the counter for every `item_id`

Comment: I see, thank you very much.  This does exactly as needed.  I seen a few CTE examples but didn't understand them.  I appeciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ([Max Bid] NUMERIC(20,4), Abs_bid_price NUMERIC(20,4),abs_date DATETIME,item_id INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(600.0000,    600.0000,    '1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM',    135827),
(600.0000,    600.0000,    '1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM',    135827),
(600.0000,    600.0000,    '1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM',    135827),
(600.0000,    600.0000,    '1/15/2014 2:40:16 PM',    135827)


SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id, [Max Bid] ORDER BY [Max Bid]DESC)
FROM @Table
)Q
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════╦════╗
║ Max Bid  ║ Abs_bid_price ║        abs_date         ║ item_id ║ rn ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════╬════╣
║ 600.0000 ║ 600.0000      ║ 2014-01-15 14:40:16.000 ║  135827 ║  1 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════╩════╝
```

Comment: But will this work when there are 2 or more valid rows that should be returned?  For instance, 2 different item ID's?  It may not have been clear in my question, but I could validly get multiple rows returned, I just want to only get one of each item ID.

Comment: Thanks to Benjamin, I see that this is the right answer.  I +1'ed it but gave Ben the answer since he posted first.  Thanks for the help.